# InsertBefore sort row in table

Tags: javascript

I have table, and I need  order (sort) th columns by available indexes (only VanilaJS not jQuery). How I can do it ?
Please see examples http://jsfiddle.net/mcqueen/AXF2Y/3/.

Comment: Questions usually have a `?` in them, and don't simply list a requirement. Until you show what you've attempted, you're just another "gimme the codez" freeloader.

Comment: Sorry. I don't freeloader... I want understand how work native js...

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
var positions = [1, 4, 2, 0, 5, 3],
    tr = document.getElementById('table-id').tHead.rows[0],
    cells = [].slice.call(tr.cells);

positions.forEach(function(pos, i) {
    tr.insertBefore(cells[pos], tr.cells[i]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ybr6E/

Helps to make an Array out of the NodeList since a NodeList updates as you change the DOM.